# Transform stream stops processing early

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to extend the node.js Transform stream twice, once to split stdin into new lines, and another to alternate lowercase and uppercase.

`SplitLines` is working as intended, but `AlternateUppercase` is not.

#### index.js

```js
const { Transform } = require('stream')

class SplitLines extends Transform {
  _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    const parsed = chunk.toString().trim()
    const results = parsed.split('\n')
    results.forEach((line) => {
      this.push(`${line}\n`)
    })
  }
}

class AlternateUppercase extends Transform {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options)
    this.isEven = false
  }

  _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    const line = chunk.toString()
    const altered = this.isEven ? line.toUpperCase() : line
    this.push(`${altered}\n`)
    this.isEven = !this.isEven
  }
}

process.stdin
  .pipe(new SplitLines())
  .pipe(new AlternateUppercase())
  .pipe(process.stdout)
```

#### How I'm testing

```
echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree' | node index.js
```

#### What I'm seeing in the terminal

```
one
```

#### What I would expect to see

```
one
TWO
three
```

Am I doing something wrong which is causing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the  [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_transform_chunk_encoding_callback), you are required to call the `callback` function in order to receive the next chunk. This is not so apparent in the `SplitLines` function because you passed the whole string as a single chunk. However, when you do the push operation repeatedly `SplitLines`, you are sending multiple chunks, so you need to call the `callback` function.

```
const { Transform } = require('stream')

class SplitLines extends Transform {
  _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    const parsed = chunk.toString().trim()
    const results = parsed.split('\n')
    results.forEach((line) => {
      this.push(`${line}\n`)
    })
  }
}

class AlternateUppercase extends Transform {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options)
    this.isEven = false
  }

  _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    const line = chunk.toString()
    const altered = this.isEven ? line.toUpperCase() : line
    this.push(`${altered}\n`)
    callback() //must call callback to receive next chunk
    this.isEven = !this.isEven
  }
}

process.stdin
  .pipe(new SplitLines())
  .pipe(new AlternateUppercase())
  .pipe(process.stdout)
```

The output would be:

```
one

TWO

three
```

The multiple new lines appeared because you `\n` at both of the transformer. To fix this, you need to add `\n` only once, ie at SplitLines or AlternateUppercase only.